# AD display name for users remains the wrong way around in TFS

Tags: tfs, active-directory

The usernames appear in our TFS work items and checkins with the wrong format - they use "Jones Dave" instead of "Dave Jones".

Is there an easy way to remedy this? Our organisation recently made a change to fix the names in Exchange server as they were the wrong way around, but not being a system administrator I'm not sure if this affected the AD or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS 2010 then the names should match what is in AD. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286562.aspx) for details.

If so, then you will have to ask your AD admin to fix the issue.